# Powershell select and remove last create item in a folder

Tags: powershell

I want to remove the newest folder (in one command (Pipeline)) in the repository c:/test but it doesn't work

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test -File | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime |
  select * |%{remove-item $_.fullname}
```

Comment: The description talks about removing a _folder_, yet you're using the `-File` switch. Did you mean to use `-Directory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Note: The question talks about removing a *folder*, yet the `-File` switch is used. If targeting a (sub)folder (directory) is intended, `-Directory` should be used, and in that case `-Recurse` should be added to the `Remove-Item` call to avoid a confirmation prompt if the target folder is *non-empty*.</sup>

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test -File | 
  Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending | # newest one first
    Select-Object -First 1 |                       # take only the first
      Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

---

In [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) you can take advantage of [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object)'s new `-Top` parameter and simplify to:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test -File | 
  Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending -Top 1 |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the Select *, rather, you need to tell the remove-item function the full path of the file to remove in a foreach statement (which is % for short), so it would look more like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\test" -Directory | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending|select  CreationTime,fullname -first 1|% {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

Comment: I want to remove the last created folder in C:\test but it doesn't do it

Comment: My bad, not sure what I was reading to confuse me; I updated it to reflect what you are looking for.